# How to use MatVector in JavaCV

Tags: opencv, vector, javacv, camera-calibration, mat

Hi I'm trying to write some camera calibration code and I'm having a hard time using MatVectors in JavaCV that should be the equivalents of std::vec in C++.

This is how i generate my image and object points:

```
Mat objectPoints = new Mat(allImagePoints.rows(),1,opencv_core.CV_32FC3);
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    for (int h=0;h<patternHeight;h++) {
        y = h*rectangleSize;
        for (int w=0;w<patternWidth;w++) {
            x = w*rectangleSize;
            objectPoints.getFloatBuffer().put(3*(patternWidth*h+w), x);
            objectPoints.getFloatBuffer().put(3*(patternWidth*h+w)+1, y);
            objectPoints.getFloatBuffer().put(3*(patternWidth*h+w)+2, 0);
        }
    }
    MatVector allObjectPointsVec = new MatVector(allImagePoints.cols());
    MatVector allImagePointsVec = new MatVector(allImagePoints.cols());
    for (int i=0;i<allImagePoints.cols();i++) {
        allObjectPointsVec.put(i,objectPoints);
        allImagePointsVec.put(i,allImagePoints.col(i));
    }
```

My image points are given in the Mat `allImagePoints` and as you can see I create corresponding vectors `allObjectPointsVec` and `allImagePointsVec` accordingly. When i try to do a camera calibration with these points i get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ni > 0 && ni == ni1) in cv::collectCalibrationData, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp, line 3193
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
```

which seems like the lengths of the image and object points don't coincide but i'm pretty sure that i got this right. Printing the MatVector objects gives

```
org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core$MatVector[address=0x2237b8a0,position=0,limit=1,capacity=1,deallocator=org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer$NativeDeallocator@4d353a7a]
org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core$MatVector[address=0x2237acd0,position=0,limit=1,capacity=1,deallocator=org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer$NativeDeallocator@772f4d0]
```

which also confuses me as I would have expected that the capacity should correspond to the length (number of matrices in the vector). If I print the size field I get the expected value. If i access a random element in the vector (e.g. allObjectPointsVec.get(i)) and print it to a string, I reveive the following:

```
AbstractArray[width=1,height=77,depth=32,channels=3] (for object points)
AbstractArray[width=1,height=77,depth=32,channels=2] (for image points)
```

which is what I would expect... Any ideas? To me this seems sort of a bug, also because I don't understand what the capacity represents if not the vector length...

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing a similar issue.